# Interesting inequality using primorial

Tags: prime-numbers

Not assuming PNT, what is $a$ in  $$(p\#_x)^a=(2^{1/2})(3^{1/3})(5^{1/5})...$$

where $p\#$ is primorial till $x$, and r.h.s is over primes.

Also answer can be asymptotic !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rhs stops at $x$, clearly $a \to 0$.  When $x$ increments to a new prime, the right side is multiplied by something very close to $1$, while the base on the left is multiplied by $x$.  So $a=\frac{\log [(2^{1/2})(3^{1/3})(5^{1/5})\dots]}{\log p\#\_x}$ will have the denominator increase by $\log x$ and the numerator hardly increase at all.

Comment: I don't know how you can if you don't know roughly how many primes there are.  With PNT you have $\log p\#\_x \sim x$  I suppose you could prove that directly, but that seems like another way of stating PNT.

Comment: No, it is the base on the left (before the power $a$) that is about $e^x$

Comment: The thing is, I had shown that the RHS is ~ x, but I am unable to show p#_n ~ e^x from that. But nevertheless thanks for help.

Comment: I get that the right side at $x=59$ is only about $18.4$, much less than $x$ and each new prime is only raising it $7\%$ here.

Comment: Well, Its asymptotic ! also I used Sigma_(log p)/p ~ log x

(also plz see my comment just after the question)